# Convert floating point numbers to decimal numbers

Tags: bash, table, floating-point

I have several 'ascii' tables in a directory, some of them have numbers expressed in decimal and some others ones in floating point, as follow:

```
1 1 1423
1 2 1589
1 3 0.85e 5
1 4 0.89e 4
1 5 8796
...
```

Is there a way to convert all the value of the tables in decimal numbers?
I heard that using `tr` editor might be useful but I can´t figure out how to operate the conversion.

Comment: well comma is not part of anything. `man ascii` is an ascii table, I don't really understand the question.

Comment: `,` is commonly used instead of `.` in many european countries as the "decimal point" delimiter

Comment: I went to school in Denmark

Comment: I'm sorry but this is still an unclear question, it's not an ascii table, and there's no way to ascertain which radix the numbers are in. Are numbers in  in a column in the same radix ? We can't see the numbers further down the list.

Comment: @XTian I think the OP just means that the file format is plain (ascii) text rather than binary (not that it is supposed to contain a table of ascii codes)

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment to ask a question, but are you sure that this is scientific notation? Generally the purpose of scientific notation is to remove all insignificant numbers. So your two examples: 0.85e 5 0.89e 4 should actually be: 8.5e 4 8.9e 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sed` script gets rid of the space after the 'e', and the `awk` script just prints out each field (multiplying $3 by 1 to "convert" it to a non-fp decimal number):

```
$ sed -e 's/e /e/g' file | awk '{print $1, $2, $3 * 1}'
1 1 1423
1 2 1589
1 3 85000
1 4 8900
1 5 8796
```

This assumes that the floating point numbers in the file:

1. have an extraneous space after the 'e'
2. omit the '+' for positive exponents
3. don't have really large exponents otherwise `awk` will print them as fp.

It's possible to get `awk` to do the 's/e /e/' transformation (so `sed` isn't needed) but it's getting late and my brain's tired.  `sed | awk` is easy and it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
{ sed 's/ /+/3' | xargs printf '%G% G% G\n'; } <in >out
```

---

```
1 1 1423
1 2 1589
1 3 85000
1 4 8900
1 5 8796
```

You'll wanna play around with the `%G` precision flags if the numbers get much larger than that.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the conversion:

```awk
awk '{print $1, $2, $3 * 10**$4}' file.csv
```

Assuming:

1. There is an space bettween the e and the actual exponent.
2. The exponent is the last field of each line.

If an specific format is needed, some form of `printf` could be used.

For example:

```awk
awk '{printf( "%s %s %g "ORS,$1,$2,$3*10**$4)}' file.csv
```

could print this:

```awk
1 1 1423 
1 2 1589 
1 3 85000 
1 4 8900 
1 5 8796 
2 8 2.589e+28
```

Last line added to show final format for big exponents.

Answer (score 1):

Other variant with `awk` **sprintf**

```
awk 'NF==4{$(NF-1)=sprintf(CONVFMT, $(NF-1)$NF);NF=3}1' file
```